# Generating random numbers with weighted distribution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, random, octave

I know how to generate random numbers in a certain range in Matlab. What i am trying to do now is generate random numbers in a range where there is more chance of getting certain ones.

For example: how could i use Matlab to generate random numbers between 0 and 2, where 50% of them will be less than 0.5?

To get numbers between 0 and 2 I would use (2-0)*rand+0. How can i do this but get a certain percentage of the numbers generated to be less than 0.5? Is there a way to do this using the rand function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion:

```
N = 10; % how many random numbers to generate
bounds = [0 0.5 1 2]; % define the ranges
prob = cumsum([0.5 0.3 0.2]); % define the probabilities
% pick a random range with probability from 'prob':
s = size(bounds,2)-cumsum(bsxfun(@lt,rand(N,1),prob),2);
% pick a random number in this range:
b = rand(1,N).*(bounds(s(:,end)+1)-bounds(s(:,end)))+bounds(s(:,end))
```

Here we have a probability of `prob(k)` to draw a number between `bounds(k)` to `bounds(k+1)`. Basically we first draw a range with defined probability, and then draw another number from the range. So we are interested only in `b`, but need `s` on the way (mainly for creating a lot of numbers in a vectorized manner).

so we get:

```
b =
  Columns 1 through 5
       0.5297      0.15791      0.88636      0.34822     0.062666
  Columns 6 through 10
     0.065076      0.54618    0.0039101      0.21155      0.82779
```

Or, for `N = 100000` we can draw:

[image: hist]

so we can see how the values are distributed between the 3 ranges in `bounds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multinomial distribution to draw the ranges, and then compute the random numbers. Here's how:

```
N = 10;
bounds = [0 0.5 1 2]; % define the ranges
d = diff(bounds);
% pick a N random ranges from a multinomial distribution:
s = mnrnd(N,[0.5 0.3 0.2]);
% pick a random number in this range:
b = rand(1,N).*repelem(d,s)+repelem(bounds(1:end-1),s)
```

so you get `s`:

```
s =
    50    39    11
```

that says you take 50 values from the first range, 39 from the second, and so on...

And you got the result in `b`:

```
b =
  Columns 1 through 5
      0.28212     0.074551      0.18166     0.035787      0.33316
  Columns 6 through 10
      0.12404     0.93468       1.9808      1.4522        1.6955
```

So basically it works the same as the first method I posted here, but it may be more accurate and/or readable. Also, I didn't test which method is faster.